# Is there any way to prevent double click on a button in HTML without using javascript/jquery?

Tags: html, css

I need to disable double click on a button just using HTML. Is there any way to do it (without using javascript/jquery) ?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

Comment: No, there is no straight forward way to achieve this using HTML and CSS alone. (Unless you want to go for really ugly and probably error-prone workarounds such as displaying a following sibling on top of the button when the button is in its focus state, or something like that. And that would not prevent a second “click” triggered via keyboard navigation either.)

Comment: A click is an event, an HTML does not provide an event handler.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML can't get the event of clicking sadly it's only possible with JS or such things that can find out `click events`.

Sadly you will be forced to use JavaScript to do this.

It's easy as that :

```
<form ...>
<input ...>
<button ... onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Submitting...'; this.form.submit();">
</form>
```